# Visual studio create installer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-installer

I am creating an installation file using VS2019 which creates two files setup.exe and install.msi. Is it possible to bundle them together for easier distribution into one setup file. Previously I used iexpress to bundle them together and using custom.bat file to execute setup after extracting. Though this is an very old technique, Is their any more innovative way we can use directly from VS2019 ?

Comment: Also consider posting your question here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects&ssr=false#qna

Comment: You can explore Inno Setup. I use it, and it's simple to create a single installer .exe from a VB.NET project build.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this guide](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-ai-ext-vs.html#section726) which makes use of Advanced Installer through a Visual Studio extension. I was able to take two projects in a solution and package them into one .msi, which installs both of the project executables when ran.

You will need to download the "Advanced Installer" Visual Studio extension (see the "Extensions" menu item in Visual Studio), as well as install Advanced Installer itself, which can be found [here](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/) (the extension will prompt you to download Advanced Installer if you attempt to use it without having it installed).  All the extension does is make use of the Advanced Installer software, but through Visual Studio.  Once you have it all configured, all you need to do is perform a build on the Advanced Installer project that you will need to add to your solution.

Comment: well I cannot pay 500usd :)

Comment: @Ranga I didn't have to pay for anything... it looks likes a free version is available, looking at [their website](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/feats-list.html).  Of course the features will be limited, but it looks like it should have what you need.